# ASP.NEt LoginStatus keep saying i'm logged in

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I tried to put a loginstatus control and before even i log in it saying LogOut.
I tried the samples for login from some other guy here and it works for me but in my page not.
When i put a loginname control to see who is logged in, i see my computer's name
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication might have set up as `mode="Windows"` in web.config.

It should be `mode="Forms"`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is more information.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
...
</authentication>
```